# How to keep the middle part of an input field hidden while editing it?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm creating an input field for a phone number in a .NET Web Application. I want to show only the first and last four digits of the number (For example 0818****5678). I also have the hiddenfield to show the full unmasked number (081812345678).

I currently have this code. When the user clicks the input field, it will reveal all the numbers. Then it will be hidden again when the user leaves the input field.

My goal is, if the user edits the number, I want the part of the input field keep hidden/masked. I'm currently stuck and have no idea how to do that.

On the last part of my JS code, I can do that if I remove the 'if'. But the '*' will also be copied to the hiddenfield.

How do I resolve this?

ASPX:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <div class="caption">Phone Number:</div>
       <asp:TextBox ID="phone" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
       <asp:HiddenField ID="currentPhone" runat="server" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
function maskedPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    let firstDigits = phoneNumber.substring(0, 4);
    let lastDigits = phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length - 4, phoneNumber.length);
    let maskedLength = phoneNumber.length - firstDigits.length - lastDigits.length;
    let maskedDigits = "";

    for (i = 0; i < maskedLength; i++) {
        maskedDigits += '*';
    }

    return maskedNumber = firstDigits + maskedDigits + lastDigits;
}

$('#<%=phone.ClientID %>').focus(function () {
      $('#<%=phone.ClientID %>').val($('#<%=currentPhone.ClientID %>').val());
});

$('#<%=phone.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
      if ($('#<%=phone.ClientID %>').val().indexOf('*') == -1) { //to avoid the * to be copied to the hiddenfield.
          $('#<%=currentPhone.ClientID %>').val($('#<%=phone.ClientID %>').val());
          $('#<%=phone.ClientID %>').val(maskedPhoneNumber($('#<%=phone.ClientID %>').val())); //to hide the field again
      }
});
```